# How to conduct row-wise operations between two pandas dataframes with nested string represented lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm looking for a pandas-friendly way of conducting row-wise operations between two nested string-represented lists in two dataframes. Here is my incomplete attempt:

```
import pandas as pd
import ast

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [0, 1, 2],
                   'nested_ls': ["[20, 15, 5]", "[8, 7, 0]", "[124, 23, 43]"]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [0, 1, 2],
                   'nested_ls': ["[10, 3, 2]", "[14, 7, 0]", "[100, 3, 20]"]})

df3 = pd.Dataframe()

# This is something along the lines of what needs to be accomplished but,
# it is evaluating the series versus the row-wise nested lists
df3['nested_ls_diff'] = ast.literal_eval(df1['nested_ls']) - ast.literal_eval(df2['nested_ls'])

# Throws - ValueError: malformed node or string: 0
```

The desired output would be a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [0, 1, 2],
                   'nested_ls_diff': ["[10, 12, 3]", "[-6, 0, 0]", "[24, 20, 23]"]})
```

Comment: What you posted doesn't even run. You didnot close `{'id': [0, 1, 2],`??

Comment: @TankoVines Next time please make sure your code runs :-).

Answer (score 2):

Your code: `ast.literal_eval(df1['nested_ls'])` tries to evaluate the **string representation** of the whole series. It's not what you want to do. Instead, you want:

```
# this gives you a series of lists
df1['nested_ls'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

or better:

```
# this gives you a numpy array
pd.eval(df1['nested_ls'])
```

So this would work for you (though not ideal):

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame()

df3['nested_ls_diff'] = list(pd.eval(df1['nested_ls']) - pd.eval(df2['nested_ls']))
```

Note that each cell in `df3['nested_ls_diff']` is a list, not a string.

---

**Update** we can just do a list comprehension here for the general case:

```
df3['nested_ls_diff'] = [[a-b for a,b in zip(*xy)] 
                         for xy in zip(pd.eval(df1['nested_ls']),pd.eval(df2['nested_ls']))
                        ]
```

Due to the nature of data (object dtype), this would perform comparable to the other approach.

Comment: I'm getting error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'` in this line `list(pd.eval(df1['nested_ls']) - pd.eval(df2['nested_ls']))`

Comment: @Ch3steR runs fine on my system with Pandas 1.1.4. `pd.eval` returns a 2D numpy array of object dtype. This may change if the lists are not of the same length.

Comment: I'm getting a `list`. My `pd.__version__` -> '1.2.2'

Comment: I tried with OP's example. Maybe they have changed `pd.eval` source code.

Comment: I'm getting the same error in 1.2.2 and also reverted to 1.1.3 I will update if I get a resolution.

Comment: @TankofVines check out the updated answer as well.